# Simple MCTS SQL Select

Tags: sql

You have two tables named Customer and SalesOrder. In the Customer table you have 1000 customers, of which 900 customers have orders in the SalesOrder table. You execute the following query to list all customers that have had at least one sale.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer.CustomerID IN (SELECT Customer.CustomerID
FROM SalesOrder)
```

You need to identify the results of the query. Which results will the query return?

```
A. No rows 
B. A warning message 
C. The 1000 rows in the Customer table
D. The 900 rows in the Customer table with matching rows in the SalesOrder table
```

The MCTS claims that the answer is C but I am not sure why not D.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the official answer. I was an idiot.

The problem is that the inner SQL Select has `Customer.CustomerID`, not `SalesOrder.CustomerID`.

Apologies.